# Length and location of longest contiguous sequence of equal values where just before and just after are smaller

Tags: java

I have a problem that asks:

> Write a program that converts its input arguments into an array of
>   integers, and then finds the length and location of the longest
>   contiguous sequence of equal values where the values of the elements
>   just before and just after this sequence are smaller. 
>   For example, if
>   the command line arguments are “1 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 3” your program should
>   output the numbers 5 3 (the first number is a zero-based offset, and
>   the second number is the length of the subsequence). If a contiguous
>   subsequence appears  at the beginning or end of the array, treat this
>   as a special case;e.g.,for input “5 5 5 5 3 8 8 8 1”your output should
>   be 0 4 (and not 5 3).  If there are multiple subsequences that satisfy
>   the above condition, then output the first one.

Updated code:

```
public class LongestPlateau {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO - Your solution
     int N= args.length;
    int [] array = new int [N]; 
    int new_length=0;
    int location=0;
    int max=0;
    int current_length=0;

     //assign digits into array
   for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
    int number = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    array [i] = number;
    }



int compare=array[0];
  for (int l=0; l<N; l++){

if (array[l] < compare){
    current_length=0;
    compare = array[l];
}
else if (array[l] == compare){
    current_length+=1;
    compare = array[l];
}

else if (array[l] > compare){
    compare=array[l];
    l++;
}

compare= array[l];

        for (int b=0; b<N; b++){
            if (current_length > max){
                max = current_length;
                location = array[l];
                new_length=max-1;
                } 
            else if (current_length==1){
                new_length=max;
            }
        }

            }
 System.out.println(location);
   System.out.println(new_length);
   }

 }
```

Issue is that for the input of "1 2 3 4" I continously get an Array Index out of bounds error.

Comment: I realize this is a fun problem to solve but I preemptively discourage others from doing the OP's homework for them. In any case @user2954736, you should post the specific issue you are seeing, how your actual results differ from your expected results, and how you've attempted to solve those specific issues so far.

Answer (score 3):

Before you start writing code, try and think how a human would have solved it.

e.g.

For every item in the input, compare it to the previous, if it's larger, start a new sequence length check (write 0 in your notebook under - "current sequence length)), if it's the same, increase it by 1, if it's less, mark that sequence length as complete. if it's larger than your largest sequence length so far (started with 0) then this is now your largest sequence, if not, ignore that sequence length and move on to the next character. (or something like this)

write these instructions to yourself as a human, and try to follow them, and fix them as you find edge cases. Once you have a working human language algorithm, writing the code will be almost self driven.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to post the specific issue you are seeing, how your actual results differ from your expected results, and what solutions you have attempted.

In any case, as for the general "how to proceed" question, I find that it often helps to work out these types of problems on paper first. Write down your sequence and step through it, observe what information you need to keep track of and what logic you need to apply to produce the desired results. Once you are able to do this, it will be far more straightforward to translate your clearly thought out algorithm into concrete code.

It appears you are at least somewhat on the right track parsing and storing your integer array, but you are a bit misguided with your `[t+?]` lookaheads. If you write this out and step through it by hand, you may be surprised at what you come up with.

Comment: i apologize, my main issue is that the error Array out of bounds exception continues to appear. I know that it is due to using t+1, however I am stumped with how to reference these positions without using t+? etc.

Comment: The caveat when looking ahead a fixed amount is you have to explicitly make sure you are not looking ahead past the end of the array, which is where your problem is. You would have to check that `t+N` is within bounds before accessing that index. Also remember your edge cases: For example, a sequence ends if the next value is smaller OR if there is no next value (end of array). Your out-of-bounds checks can work directly in to your edge case logic. Work it out on paper / in a text editor / in your head first. There is, for example, never really a reason you should be looking ahead by 3.

Comment: I believe I have figured out my solution to that particular problem. However, now the one issue i am having is if I were to input in "1 2 3 4" it outputs index out of bounds and I can't seem to trace where that is happening. the new code is above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full program description with test cases:

Given an array of integers int A[], find the length and location of the longest contiguous sequence of equal values for which the values of the elements just before and just after this sequence are smaller.

You should just print these two numbers (first is the length and second is the starting index of the plateau).

To complete the definition, we can consider there are imaginary index positions at A[-1] and A[A.length] where A[-1] < A[0] and A[A.length] < A[A.length-1]. Therefore, the plateau can start/end at both ends of array A. This condition guarantees the existence of a plateau. A plateau can be of length 1.

Example 1:

```
java LongestPlateau 1 2 2 2 2 1
```

With this command line arguments, program should print:

```
4
1
```

Example 2:

```
java LongestPlateau 1 2 2 2 2 3
```

With this command line arguments, program should print:

```
1
5
```

Example 2:

```
java LongestPlateau 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

With this command line arguments, program should print:

```
4
12
```

Example 2:

```
java LongestPlateau 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 1
```

With these command-line arguments, the program should print:

```
4
15
```

Here is my solution:

```
public class LongestPlateau {
private static int[] parseInputArray(String[] args) {
    int[] value = new int[args.length+1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < args.length; i++){
        if (i == args.length-1) value[i] = 0; // this imaginary last value of the array ensures that if the plateau is the last value of the array, then it outputs the correct answer
        value[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    return value;
}
public static void printLargestPlateau(int[] values) {
    int biggestStartIndex = -1;
    int biggestLength = 0;
    int currentIndex = 1;
    int currentPlateauStartIndex = 1;
    int currentLength = 1;
    boolean plateauStarted = false;
    while (currentIndex < values.length) {
        if(isStartOfPlateau(currentIndex, values)){
            currentLength = 1;
            plateauStarted = true;
            currentPlateauStartIndex = currentIndex;
        } else if (isEndOfPlateau(currentIndex, values)) {
            if(plateauStarted && currentLength > biggestLength){
                biggestLength = currentLength;
                biggestStartIndex = currentPlateauStartIndex;
            }
            plateauStarted = false;
            currentLength = 1;
        } else {
            currentLength++;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
    System.out.println(biggestLength +"\n"+biggestStartIndex);
}

private static boolean isStartOfPlateau(int index, int[] values){
    if(index <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    return values[index-1] < values[index];
}

private static boolean isEndOfPlateau(int index, int[] values){
    if(index <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    return values[index - 1] > values[index];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = parseInputArray(args);
    printLargestPlateau(values);
}
}
```